# Can't get a complete plot for a piecewise function

Tags: plotting

I am having trouble showing the entire y-axis for the given piece wise plot:

```
y[x_] := Piecewise[{{2, -2 <= x <= -1}, {1, -1 <= x <= 0}, {2, 
     0 <= x <= 1}, {3, 1 <= x <= 2}}];
Plot[y[x], {x, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "f_n(t)"}, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

I tried PlotRange Full, All or Automatic, but as you can see, the plot starts with y=1, and not y=0:

[image]

This is odd. How can I show the plot from y=0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manually specify that you want $y$-axis to begin at $0$.

```
Plot[y[x], {x, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "f_n(t)"}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, Automatic}}]
```

Comment: Or just `PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}`